# How to know image with a url which receives 204 no content as response is loaded or not

Tags: javascript

I have an image tag and the url of the image tag is some url which receives response code as 204 No Content.

Since it is 204 - No Content, it is neither called loadHandler not errorHandler. Because of this I am not able to find, whether the image is loaded or not.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
   console.log('Image Loaded');
}
img.onerror = function () {
   console.log('Image Load Failed');
}
img.src = "https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=&c2=6005068&c3=6005068&c15=C67BD3C1&cv=1.3&cj=1";
```

since the response of the url `https://sb.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=&c2=6005068&c3=6005068&c15=C67BD3C1&cv=1.3&cj=1` is `204 No Content` load/error handlers are not getting called and I am not able to find whether image loaded or failed.

Is there any way that we can know whether image loaded or failed?

Comment: When I run your code on a snippet it works properly, returns 'Image Load Failed' for the link you provided (request returns 204) and returns 'Image Loaded' for other image URL that resolves with 200

Comment: Sorry, when I ran, it did not run properly and I did not get error msg. Now I am getting that error msg.
Thanks Renan

Comment: No problem. I flagged your question to be closed, since it's not really helpful to anyone in the future.

Comment: Thank you for flagging it as closed